# Count occurrences of a condition in a list vertically, storing results in a list?

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have a dataframe containing three states and their results for a given test stored as lists:

```
list1 <- list(c(-40, 22, 10))
list2 <- list(c(-1, 18, -39))
list3 <- list(c(22, -5, 2))

dat <- data.frame(State = c("Iowa", "Wisconsin", "Ohio"))
dat$Tests <- c(list1, list2, list3)
```

I want to count the number of negative instances *vertically*. So the first test would have 2 instances (-40, -1), the second test would have 1 instance (-5), and the third test would have 1 instance (-39). The result would look like this, stored as a list:

```
results <- data.frame(Results = list(c(2, 1, 1))
```

Two questions:

1. How does one do this using R?
2. Is there a way to do using dplyr? (Purely optional; it's my preferred toolkit.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a matrix of `Tests` and using `colSums` count number of negative values in each column.

```
colSums(do.call(rbind, dat$Tests) < 0)
#[1] 2 1 1
```

Using `bind_cols` function from `dplyr` you could do something similar.

```
rowSums(dplyr::bind_cols(dat$Tests) < 0)
```

Comment: Ronak, won't bind_rows work if the lists are not named and have default [[1]], [[2]] ?

Comment: For `bind_rows` you'll need to convert it into dataframe/tibble first.

Comment: This is great, thank you @RonakShah! Question: How would I plug this into a `dplyr` pipe chain? For example:

```sum_results <- dat %>%
rowSums(dplyr::bind_cols(Tests) < 0) %>%
other_stuff_using_dplyr```

Comment: @RonakShah Nevermind, I figured out how to make it work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse` approach

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
dat %>% 
    mutate(Results = map(Tests, `<`, 0) %>% 
          reduce(`+`))
#      State       Tests Results
#1      Iowa -40, 22, 10       2
#2 Wisconsin -1, 18, -39       1
#3      Ohio   22, -5, 2       1
```

---

Or using `base R` with `Reduce` and `lapply`

```
dat$Results <- Reduce(`+`, lapply(dat$Tests, `<`, 0))
dat$Results
#[1] 2 1 1
```